# Mass Transit - Channel unusable due to ContinuationTimeout

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

Few weeks ago we migrated MassTransit from 7.2.0 (two years old) to 8.0.11 then quickly after that to 8.0.16.

For information :

- we have about 5 - 6 distincts 'production' environments, deployed not exactly in the same way (K8S / classic VMs Windows and/or linux). Each environment has from 1 to 10 dedicated rabbits instances (Linux VM or Docker)
- it is a multi-tenant solution ; each tenant have a dedicated vhost on one of the Rabbit
- each dotnet process may process several tenant ; therefore there's multiple MassTransit instance (1 for each tenant ; connecting to a specific vhost on a specific rabbit instance).

In our Dev and QA environment we did not see that because it does not have the workload of production, but on each production environment, we encountered a massive loss of performance.

We managed to find the change in MassTransit that causing this : the BatchPublish disabled by default in version 8. Enabling back this settings restored almost the performance we had before.

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(opts => opts.AddCustomConfigurations());
    
    cfg.ConnectBusObserver(new BusLoggerObserver(_serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<BusLoggerObserver>>()));

    var connectionName = _configuration.GetApplicationName();
    cfg.Host(options.Hosts.First(), vhostName, connectionName, h =>
    {
        if (options.Hosts.Length > 0)
        {
            h.UseCluster(c =>
            {
                foreach (var host in options.Hosts)
                {
                    c.Node(host);
                }
            });
        }
        h.Username(options.Username);
        h.Password(options.Password);
        h.ContinuationTimeout(options.ContinuationTimeout);
        h.ConfigureBatchPublish(c =>
        {
            c.Enabled = options.BatchPublishEnabled;
            c.MessageLimit = options.BatchPublishMessageLimit;
            c.Timeout = options.BatchPublishTimeout;
        });
    });
});
```

In the MassTransit documentation and forums, it is said that is not required, and if it is, it is probably caused by bad latencies on the RabbitMQ. Does anybody have insights on this ?

However, the real issue, since we migrated, is 1 exception we frequently have :
`The channel was closed: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Application, code=500, text=''Channel unusable due to continuation timeout'', classId=0, methodId=0 1`

When this exception occurs ; the MassTransit instance seems to be locked and we can no longer send or receive anything ; and since the app entirely rely on MassTransit / RabbbitMQ ; it is a dead process. We have to restart the process to restore the availability. We tryed to increase the value but we still have the exception.

This is causing me nightmares, does anybody had the same issue and/or have a solution to that situation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the [ContinuationTimeout](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/rabbitmq#host-configuration) to a value suitable for your slow/unreliable environment.

Also [discussed here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/3422).

If you're seeing significantly high broker confirmation times causing the continuation timeout, you likely have an undersized broker configuration which is causing it.

> As to the performance when using batch publishing, for every person that says it should be on by default, there is another person saying it should be off by default. Once you configured it as expected, you saw it return to normal which is good.

Comment: I searched on forums a lot before posting this question, and I have seen the discussion you mentioned, but could not find a solution. You mention it *should* create a new channel ; but in our case, it does not and the process stays stuck.

We increased the value but it still remains issues. 

However, our RabbitMq infra did not change but since we use MassTransit 8, we have this kind of exception ; everything was working as expected in MassTransit 7. 

The RabbitMq servers seems to be well sized ; CPU and RAM are good. Unfortunately we are still using 'classic' queues ; could it related?

Comment: ContinuationTimeout was added by the RabbitMQ.Client update, not MassTransit. As for MassTransit not recovering from it? That seems like a thing fixed over the past year, but without a complete reproducible case it's impossible to guess what strange edge case might be in your usage of it. If you have a support agreement, contact [support](https://masstransit.io/support).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I may contact the support / you to request some consulting / guidance.

Comment: I can confirm this is still happening with 8.0.15. RabbitMQ is running fine and other services use it properly, but the MassTransit project prints that error every second since 12h and do not reconnect.